# How do I "consolidate" a specific field from multiple rows into multiple - different - fields in one single row?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

**The situation:** 3 source tables:

**1. Users** (containing unique ID and user-specific properties like `firstName`, `givenName`, `StreetAddress`, etc)

**2. MigrationFeatures** (containing unique ID and `Feature_Name`)

**3. Link_Users_and_Features** (containing both the unique IDs from `Users` and `Features` as well as a `Status` column (int) )

In the link table, for each user there are exactly as many rows as there are rows in the `Feature` table and each of these rows (per user) is linked to exactly one `Feature`. Each link row contains also a status value column which can have a different value - according to the migration status of the particular `Feature` for a specific user.

**The Goal**:

Having a fully dynamic query / SP that returns one row for each user with the migration status of each `Feature` for that particular user - each migration status column shold be named according to the `Feature_Name` from the corresponding `Feature` from the `Features` table. When I add an additional `Feature` into the `Feature` table, no manual modification to the desired query code must be made.

Hint: the `Feature` table has already an insert trigger which creates for each user this additional column and there is referential integrity on the relevant columns so all users will always have all corresponding rows in the link table for all `Features`.

**Why do I want to have that:**

Until now, I have one single table containing all the user-specific columns (`Name, givenName, StreetAddress,` etc) as well as all the migration feature status columns (`SIDhist migrated, homefolder migrated,` etc), holding all migration status data for all users.

Unfortunately, this is fully static and whenever I am adding a new `Feature`, I have to modify this master table. In the future, less skilled persons will use the underlying system and they will not go into the DB code or schema but only adding records to the `Feature` and the `user` table.

Here the code to create the users DB:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
        [Users_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [FMOUser_givenName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [FMOUser_sn] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [FMOUser_streetAddress] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [ExcludeFromMigration] [bit] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Users_ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
```

Here the code to create the Features table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Features](
    [Features_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Feature_Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Features] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Features_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

the code to create the Link table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[link_Users__with__Features](
    [link_Users__with__Features_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FMO_Users_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Features_Migration_Core_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StatusValue] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_link_Users__with__Features] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [link_Users__with__Features_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

What did I already rResearch?

I have found the following example:

http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/1673127-view-multiple-records-single-row.html

This does put single columns from multiple rows under new column name in one single row but it is not dynamic - means: it does not pull out the target column names out from the corresponding "Feature" row from the `Features` table nor can it handle a dynamic number of `Features`.

As I am relatively new to T-SQL I am lost how to solve this challenge.

As this is my first question at stack Overflow, please forgive me if I have missed a formality. Please correct me and I will do better :-)

Hint: I have looked up the proposed "duplicates" to my question but there seems none which even slightly matches my question.

Comment: From the looks of it, `sql server dynamic pivot` should be the keywords to search either the web or specifically this site for.

Comment: Thanks, that led me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does what I required in my initial question: (please note that I have introduced an additional view: view_Users_*and*_StatusValues which binds together Users, the link table and features )

It is inspired from: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/

Code:

```
use [your_database]

-- *** Get the column names for the target 'table' out from the features table
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N',' + QUOTENAME(Feature_Name)
  FROM (SELECT p.Feature_Name FROM dbo.Features AS p
  INNER JOIN dbo.link_Users__with__Features AS o
  ON p.Features_ID = o.Features_ID
  GROUP BY p.Feature_Name) AS x;

-- *** remove unneccessary, leading ',' ***
set @columns = STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
-- print @columns

-- *** Create the SQL code which will produce the correct output table ***
SET @sql = N'
select * from dbo.view_FMO_Users__and__StatusValues
pivot(
        max(StatusValue) -- use any aggregate function (needed for pivoting) 
        for Feature_Name in (' + @columns + ')) as FeatureStatusValue'

-- PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note for me personally: How to give output columns from pivot meaningful names:

```
(select 
            Betrieb = [200], IP = [310], port = [311]    -- Give friendly names to output columns
 from 

(select i.INTERFACEID, ioptions.OPTION_IDENTIFIER, ioptions.value from 
(tac.I_A_INTERFACE_OPTIONS ioptions join tac.G_M_INTERFACES i on i.INTERFACEID = ioptions.INTERFACEID)
 where (OPTION_IDENTIFIER=200 or OPTION_IDENTIFIER=310 or OPTION_IDENTIFIER=311) and i.TYPE = 700) 
  temp

pivot(
        max(value) -- use any aggregate function (needed for pivoting) 
        for OPTION_IDENTIFIER in (
        [310],[311],[200])
        ) as output
)
```